# Can someone help me make a loop where the text for detail and state change every second from Text to Text2 and back to Text

Tags: javascript

```
var status = {
  rPE: true,
  name: "",
  type: 1,
  details: "Text",
  state: "Text",
  largeText: "DoesntWork",
  application_id: "36",
};
```

If you can have it where Text for both details and state can change every second to Text2 for both and back to Text (Looped) that'd be great

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `setInterval`

```js
let status = {"rPE": true, "name": "", "type": 1, "details": "Text", "state": "Text", "largeText": "DoesntWork", "application_id": "36"}

window.setInterval(()=>{
    const a = {"details": "Text", "state": "Text"},
          b = {"details": "Text2", "state": "Text2"};
    if(status.details === a.details){
        status.details = b.details;
        status.state = b.details;
    } else {
        status.details = a.details;
        status.state = a.details;
    }
    console.log(status);
}, 1000);
```